# Autodesk Forge BIM360 upload file to S3 gets 403 Forbidden, how to fix?

Tags: amazon-s3, autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I am trying to use the new forge upload-to-S3 process
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/upload-file/
since the current process will soon be dead. For anyone not familiar, see the following description:

> We are migrating to the direct-s3 approach for uploading/downloading objects from the OSS >buckets. Here are some related blog posts on this topic for your reference. Our SDK >migration is still on the way. Once it's done, we will have another blog post announcement >for that. Please bear with us.

[See comments below for links.]

> Meanwhile, we also asked our product team to update the tutorial with this direct-s3 >approach. Hope it would be delivered soon.

Unfortunately the new documentation is a bit light on the actual upload specifications, "Step 5". [. Net and Node.js examples are nice; but I am using Java so there isn't a direct correlation.]

Also, the Curl example as shown does not work with the header, it gets an "Invalid Argument -- Only one auth mechanism allowed; only the X-Amz-Algorithm query parameter, Signature query string parameter or the Authorization header should be specified" error. When I remove the header, the Curl command runs and I get no response at all.

I am able to generate the "signed S3 upload" urls; but when I make a call to upload, I simply get a "403 Forbidden" error with no additional information. I should have complete permissions on this project (unless there is something new and special that has to be set up for S3???).

Edit: another item that is unclear; once the upload actually completes and we POST "buckets/:bucketKey/objects/:objectKey/signeds3upload" to complete the object creation process, must we still make the "create first version" call ( https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/:project_id/items)? Or is that unnecessary at this point?

```
//here is the function I am using
public static void uploadImageS3(String fileName, String path, String uRL) {
        MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_JPEG = MediaType.parse("image/jpeg");
        try {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
           .addFormDataPart("file", fileName, RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_JPEG, new 
             File(path)))
           .build();
            Request request = new Request.Builder().url(uRL)
            .post(requestBody).build();
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
            throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
        }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
           String Error = ex.getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Here are the links from the quoted text above: [https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/data-management-oss-object-storage-service-migrating-direct-s3-approach](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/data-management-oss-object-storage-service-migrating-direct-s3-approach)
[https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/direct-s3-nodejs-samples](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/direct-s3-nodejs-samples)
[https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/direct-s3-net-samples](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/direct-s3-net-samples)

Comment: There is one mention in the documentation regarding the 403 error: "If the response code is 403, the upload URLs have expired; go back to step #2". But this is on multi-part uploads and I am using just one small upload. I have also set the expiration up to 15 minutes, so there's no way the url has expired.